# What does the "-webkit-min-logical-width" property do?

Tags: css, webkit, vendor-prefix

I've recently come across a problem in CSS where I set the `min-width` property to a certain value that works in Firefox but breaks in Webkit. While playing around a little bit with the Chrome inspector, I discovered the property `-webkit-min-logical-width` that, when set to a different value than the `min-width`, fixes my layout issues in Chrome! Does anyone know exactly what this property is supposed to do? I googled for it and didn't come up with anything, even on webkit's website.

**EDIT** Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/CKRZg/) demonstrating this in action. View in both Chrome and FF to see the difference. It appears that it may be a min-width override?

Comment: Did you google it with or without the leading `-`?

Comment: I already did. Nothing about a definition comes up, just that it exists

Comment: @radek without the leading `-` and in quotes. My googlefu may be weak, but it is not THAT weak ;)

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit-min-logical-width` only overrides `min-width` when it's placed after it. When in front, `min-width` is chosen.

This basically makes them equal and my guess would be that `-webkit-min-logical-width` was the first webkit implementation of `min-width`. It was a temporary name that still has to work to avoid breaking older websites :).

just my cup of tea :)

EDIT:

this might be it: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-writing-modes/#abstract-dimensions

> measure or logical width
>
> A measurement in the inline dimension: refers to the physical
>   width (horizontal dimension) in
>   horizontal writing modes, and to the
>   physical height (vertical dimension)
>   in vertical writing modes. (The term
>   measure derives from its use in
>   typography.)

Comment: this is more information than i had before, but i guess i still don't get when to use one or the other, except in my case for abuse :)

Comment: well you shouldn't use it as it is not documented. It can be used as a webkit hack to differentiate it from ff for example but just don't use unknown development properties.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use it. Non standard and probably deprecated or soon to be removed (see below). Here is the simple definition -

`min-logical-width` is `min-width` when the writing mode is horizontal.

`min-logical-width` is `min-height` when the writing mode is vertical.

I found the [original draft specification revision](https://dev.w3.org/cvsweb/~checkout~/csswg/css3-writing-modes/Attic/Overview.html?rev=1.11;content-type=text%2Fhtml;hideattic=0#logical-width). If you scroll down a bit, you will find a table that maps the properties to the known properties according to the writing mode.

Also, I believe [it is going away soon](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/VbPI65jBMIc) and will render it completely useless for hacking your CSS for Chrome.